# Flutter error with hero without using animation

Tags: flutter

```
  Exception caught by scheduler library ═════════════════════════════════
  The following assertion was thrown during a scheduler callback:
```

There are multiple heroes that share the same tag within a subtree.
Within each subtree for which heroes are to be animated (i.e. a PageRoute subtree), each Hero must have a unique non-null tag. In this case, multiple heroes had the following tag:

```
 <default Floating Action Button tag>
```

Here is the subtree for one of the offending heroes:

Hero tag:

```
 <default Floating Action Button tag>
```

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: Your hero tag names must be unique, you are clearly using the same tag name on multiple places.

Comment: You cannot use same name for heroes tag, you can name it null or a random number.

Comment: please mention your problem